# Unable to access in "phpMyAdmin" on localhost

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was working on WordPress Theme Development. Suddenly my phpMyAdmin stopped to work and showing these error message. I am not getting any solution to fix this
Note: I am using XAMPP server

[image]

Comment: show a clip of your error message.

Comment: At least you should check error message and research it

Comment: try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: I have tried "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". But still it is not working

Comment: @curiosity I attached screenshot of error message